# dict type gives error "TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable"

Tags: pandas

Working in a jupyter notebook, I have a column that was parsed from nested json:

```
[x for x in df['report_location']]
[ {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [-122.340152, 47.613134]},
 {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [-122.25481, 47.517345]},
 {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [-122.36052, 47.630457]},
 {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [-122.348843, 47.628917]},
 {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [-122.318122, 47.612931]}]
```

I can get at the data.

```
df['report_location'][0]['coordinates']
[-122.340152, 47.613134]
```

It looks like a Series of type dict.

```
[type(x) for x in df['report_location']]
[dict,
dict,
dict,...
```

But, surprise, now it's a float. Why?

```
[x['coordinates'] for x in df['report_location']]
TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Try `pd.series(map(type, df['report_location'])).value_counts()`... maybe there was a parsing error or a fluke in the data source

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, RichieV. Something amiss in the parsing.

```
pd.Series(map(type, df['report_location'])).value_counts()
<class 'dict'>     253514
<class 'float'>       345
dtype: int64
```

Data was parsed from json, column headers as keys. The key/value for `report_location` was missing from some items. For those rows the values were stored as `nan`, which is a special `float` value.